# Carregar função Javascript ao abrir a página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não entendo muito do assunto, porém, vou tentar explicar.
Atualmente quando passo o *mouse* por cima de uma `div` com a classe `tooltips`, é executado o script abaixo:

```
$('.tooltips').tooltip();
```

Porém, gostaria que isto acontecesse logo ao carregar a página, não sendo preciso passar o *mouse* sobre a `div` ou clicar nela.

Como é que eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pode ser bem provável que está função mostre o tooltip apos um evento hover no elemento. Neste caso uma alternativa seria disparar uma trigger com o evento no elemento para ativar o tooltip.

Comment: Era **[isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/95642/11886)** que querias fazer @RodrigoSegatto ? Se não, podias [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/95611/edit) a tua pergunta, aprimorá-la e adicionar-lhe mais informações?

Answer (score 1):

Podes fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#link").tooltip({ show: {duration: 800} });
    $("#link").trigger('mouseenter');
});

$('html').click(function() {
    $("#link").trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

O que isto vai fazer é mostrar o `tooltip` utilizando a opção [**`.show`**](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-show) quando o documento estiver pronto, simulando a ação de `mouseenter/mouse hover` no link e depois quando clicado em qualquer lugar do documento, remove essa ação com o `mouseleave`.

Aqui tens um exemplo online no jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nf0hhmm2/

Answer (score 0):

Já que você está usando JQuery e não Javascript puro, experimente `$(document).ready(suaFunção)`

Comment: isto: $(document).ready(tooltip); ? Não funcionou aqui

Comment: Agora que entendi. Essa função é do próprio JQuery. Realmente, ela não foi feita para fazer o que você está querendo. Uma alternativa seria disparar esse evento na mão, mas você pode imaginar o caos (hover em todos ao mesmo tempo??)

Comment: Deu certo assim: $('.tooltips').tooltip('show');

Comment: com ou sem $(document).ready()?

Comment: Sem. Porém, quanto tiro o mouse de cima da classe tooltips, ele some. O que posso colocar para resolver?

Comment: Ele some depois que vc tira o mouse de cima de um dos lugares onde têm tooltip? Bem, nem imaginei que funcionaria, mas eu tentaria adicionar uma outra chamada a esse método no onblur (evento que dispara ao tirar o mouse de cima) desses componentes, então.

Comment: Pablo, não consegui compreender..

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30923/discussion-between-pablo-and-rodrigo-segatto).